# Regluar expression problem. It does not find the needed part of the string

Tags: c#, regex

I have to parse a build log file and find some header file which went missing when I exported my working sandbox. In C++ I managed to solve this issue, but the same pattern didn't work for C#.

These are the line which I want to parse to get the name of the missing header files:

> "Src/EBS\FSW/CustSW/CustSW_generic/RSC/Src/gen/rsc_iohandling_types.h",
>
> line 1: error (dcc:1621): can't find include file FSW/CustSW/CustSW_plugin/RSC_plugin/RSC_Volvo_QC1/Src/gen/rsc_interfacestructures_types.h
>   "out/VOLVO/QC1/gen/Src/EBS\FSW/CustSW/CustSW_plugin/RSC_plugin/RSC_Volvo_QC1/Src/gen/rsc_b_interfacestructures_types.h",
>
> line 19: error (dcc:1621): can't find include file FSW/CustSW/CustSW_generic/RSC/Src/gen/rsc_cpif.h
>   "out/VOLVO/QC1/gen/Src/EBS\FSW/CustSW/CustSW_generic/RSC/Src/gen/tvc_safe_types.h",
>
> line 19: error (dcc:1621): can't find include file FSW/CustSW/CustSW_generic/RSC/Src/gen/rsc_cpif.h
>   "Src/EBS\FSW/CustSW/CustSW_generic/RSC/Src/gen/rsc_iohandling_types.h",
>
> line 3: error (dcc:1621): can't find include file rsc_qm_interfacestructures_types.h

This is the current code which is faulty:

```
string[] errLns = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(logFilePath);
List<string> hdrFiles = new List<string>();
string rgxPat = @"can't find include (\w+/)*(\w+\.[hed|he|hdb|h])";
Regex incLRgx = new Regex(rgxPat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

foreach (string actLine in errLns)
{
   Match match = incLRgx.Match(actLine);
   hdrFiles.Add(match.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

I only want to have the file names without the relative path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\bcan't\s+find\s+include\s+file\s+(?:\w+/)*(\w+\.(?:hed?|hdb|h))\b
```

and grab Group 1. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jbJLxT/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `can't\s+find\s+include\s+file\s+` - `can't find include file` with 1+ whitespaces in between the words and after it
- `(?:\w+/)*` - 0+ occurrences of 1+ word chars followed with `/`
- `(\w+\.(?:hed?|hdb|h))` - Group 1: 1+ word chars, `.` and then `he`, `hed`, `hbd` or `h`
- `\b` - word boundary.

C# code:

```
string errLns = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(logFilePath);
List<string> hdrFiles = new List<string>();
string rgxPat = @"\bcan't\s+find\s+include\s+file\s+(?:\w+\/)*(\w+\.(?:hed?|hdb|h))\b";
Regex incLRgx = new Regex(rgxPat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
hdrFiles.AddRange(incLRgx.Matches(errLns).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it work's fine. It look like I have to learn the regex syntax again.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, Can I ask you again in another regex topic? I used the site which you sent me the regex demo and it showed me that the pattern is OK but in C# it does not match. Can I reach you somehow with this question?

Comment: @BéresZoli Can you share the C# fiddle/demo? Did you use a verbatim string literal to define the regex?

Comment: @BéresZoli If the issue is unique, please post another question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern `can't find include file .+\.(?=hed|he|hdb|h)`

`can't find include file` - match `can't find include file` literally

`.+` - match one or more of any characters

`\.` = match `.` literally

`(?=hed|he|hdb|h)` - positive lookahead - assert that what follows is one of `hed` , `he`, `hdb` or `h`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/w7Rmpy/1)